# Dynamic Cosmos SQL query from Azure functions

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We have a Cosmos DB from which we are trying to retrieve data using different parameters using a http triggered function API.
I'm aware of the cosmos input binding but for this I need to put in my SQL query in the function.json file and this is fine if all the parameters are present in the query.
The problem is, I would like to fetch data based on different parameters and it is possible that not all these parameters will be sent for each query. Is there a way this function API dynamic enough to create the SQL query in run time and fetch the data from Cosmos?

Instead of using the input binding, I tried using the Cosmos python SDK but was getting the below error. "*No module named 'azure.cosmos'*".

When I normally run a python program to access cosmos outside functions, it is working fine which tells me that I have the necessary libraries already imported. But this is failing when calling from python functions. I've already checked that I'm pointing to the correct interpreter (python 3.8).

Is there something I'm missing? Below is my code :

{

```
import logging
from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        endpoint = "https://anucosmos123.documents.azure.com:443/"
        key = 'kbN3EzLfxVYUDg4dRG0gtyehgnrD2kM410jyzfUIK1N8dl11tmVkZcig9PKNmccJR89jHdYIeHKnjH7JnMYo6Q=='
        client = CosmosClient(endpoint, key)
        database_name = 'mydb'
        database = client.create_database_if_not_exists(id=database_name)
        container_name= 'mycoll'
        container = database.create_container_if_not_exists(id=container_name,partition_key=PartitionKey(path="/name"),
            offer_throughput=400)

        query = 'SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name = "Anupam"'
        items = list(container.query_items(query=query, enable_cross_partition_query=True))
        print(items)
        return func.HttpResponse(items, status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
             status_code=200
        )
```

}

And below is the error I received.
{

```
[2021-02-10T05:05:48.655Z] Worker process started and initialized.[2021-02-10T05:05:48.726Z] Worker failed to function id 89f6dacb-3136-4a73-89f4-7525bdc69fe0.

[2021-02-10T05:05:49.388Z] Result: Failure
Exception: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure.cosmos'. Troubleshooting Guide: https://aka.ms/functions-modulenotfound
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 271, in _handle__function_load_request
    func = loader.load_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 34, in call
    raise extend_exception_message(e, message)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 32, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 76, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Functions1\myhttp1\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from azure.cosmos import exceptions, CosmosClient, PartitionKey
.
[2021-02-10T05:05:49.397Z] Worker failed to function id dc05d956-83c3-44fd-9dfd-304c3f3db8ca.
[2021-02-10T05:05:49.398Z] Result: Failure
Exception: AttributeError: module 'azure.functions' has no attribute 'In'
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 271, in _handle__function_load_request
    func = loader.load_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 32, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 76, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Functions1\SBTopicTrigger1\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage, inputdocument: func.In[func.Document], outputSbMsg:func.ServiceBusMessage):
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the code of your function?

Comment: The incoming json-based input is mainly to satisfy the dynamic incoming of binding. And, for cosmosdb sdk, it should be no problem to use it directly.

Comment: @BowmanZhu : Editted my question with the code and error received.

Comment: Have you install the azure.cosmos globally or just install by requirements.txt?

Comment: Judging from the error report, the specific logic of the function is not even entered. The first line fails. I think you did not install the module? Are you testing locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We have a Cosmos DB from which we are trying to retrieve data using
> different parameters using a http triggered function API. I'm aware of
> the cosmos input binding but for this I need to put in my SQL query in
> the function.json file and this is fine if all the parameters are
> present in the query. The problem is, I would like to fetch data based
> on different parameters and it is possible that not all these
> parameters will be sent for each query. Is there a way this function
> API dynamic enough to create the SQL query in run time and fetch the
> data from Cosmos?

The dynamic that binding can achieve are relatively limited. If you pass in json, you can get the key value of the passed json data in the binding definition (this is considered dynamic in a sense). However, it is recommended to use the cosmosdb SDK to achieve dynamics.

> Instead of using the input binding, I tried using the Cosmos python
> SDK but was getting the below error. "No module named 'azure.cosmos'".
>
> When I normally run a python program to access cosmos outside
> functions, it is working fine which tells me that I have the necessary
> libraries already imported. But this is failing when calling from
> python functions. I've already checked that I'm pointing to the
> correct interpreter (python 3.8).

I can reproduce, this is your error(I can also import with no problems when using common python script):

[image]

I think the problem comes from your are running on a virtual environment and you have already activate it.

So, two ways:

Don't activate the virtual environment, and use command 'func host start' to start your function(This will start with global environment.).

Or just add 'azure.cosmos' to requirements.txt file like this:

```
azure-functions
azure.cosmos
```

The above can solve the current error you encounter.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

I added the 2 requirements into my requirements.txt and got the below error.
Any suggestions on how to fix the "AttributeError: module 'azure.functions' has no attribute 'In'" error?

```
{[2021-02-10T06:34:16.248Z] Worker failed to function id 4af477f8-eff0-4937-b87f-98f7828d95ec.
[2021-02-10T06:34:16.250Z] Result: Failure
Exception: AttributeError: module 'azure.functions' has no attribute 'In'
Stack:   File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 271, in _handle__function_load_request
    func = loader.load_function(
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\utils\wrappers.py", line 32, in call
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Azure Functions Core Tools\workers\python\3.8/WINDOWS/X64\azure_functions_worker\loader.py", line 76, in load_function
    mod = importlib.import_module(fullmodname)
  File "C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Functions1\SBTopicTrigger1\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    def main(message: func.ServiceBusMessage, inputdocument: func.In[func.Document], outputSbMsg:func.ServiceBusMessage):
.}
```

Comment: Please don't post an answer, I won't get any prompt if you do this.  Where do you use 'In'? The details of the problem is not enough.  And this should be another question. I think you need to post a new question and give the function.json(Please do not mix multiple questions in one SO question, this does not conform to SO specifications). By the way, I noticed that you did not even communicate with other answerers about the progress of the question in the previous questions. If an answer solves your question, please mark it as the answer to this question. This is an incentive for the answerers